# Threejs draw a shape from just points

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, geometry

Given a list of `Vector3`s in no order, I would like to create an ordering of the elements such that when I draw a `Shape` from those points, I will be outlining the shape without ever going across its face.

How would you do this? I think the first thing is to always pick the point closest to you, but what if more than one point have exactly the same distance from a point?

Let's call the point we're on `x`, and a potential "neighbor" (point whose distance to `x` is minimal) `y` where there can be multiple `y`s.

I've thought about these two approaches:

- Find the center of mass by averaging out the positions of the points, then make sure that going from `x` to `y` never goes through the center. This approach has many problems like 1. it's not guaranteed to cross the CoM or 2. imagine a fidget spinner with just two circles, and one much smaller than the other. When tracing the smaller bit, the center of mass is never crossed (or come close to), but we might still ran into problems
- Randomly pick any other three points, and make sure that `y` is not within the triangle created. But there are cases where `y` is the correct choice, but still falls within the triangle (imagine a shape one of whose edge is created by two tangent circles).

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you creating a shape or a linepath?

Comment: A shape. Lines are much easier, but I need to be able to use an `ExtrudeGeometry`

Comment: I think you're trying to find the three dimensional "convex hull". Google around for that phrase and see if it helps.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for - there's an MIT lecture on it too. Thanks a lot!!